# python3 - Adding link import url

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to add the url to the links that I receive. How can I do this?
My source code is this way

```
</a></li><li><a href="/archive/2017-06-13">
        Link title 2017-06-13
      </a></li><li><a href="/archive/2017-06-12">
        Link title 2017-06-12
      </a></li><li><a href="/archive/2017-06-11">
```

And my python 3 codes

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
url = "https://myurl.com"
parseurl = "https://myurl.com/archivelist"
url_readd = urllib.request.urlopen(parseurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_readd, 'html.parser')
project_href = [i['href'] for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if i['href'] != "#"]

for string in project_href:
  print(append url(string))
```

Comment: Where and how do you want to "add" them? Can you post an example?

Comment: https://myurl.com/archive/2017-06-13

https://myurl.com/archive/2017-06-12

https://myurl.com/archive/2017-06-11

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for string concatenation (maybe even string formatting), there are a few possibilities:

```
for string in project_href:
    print(url + string)
    print("".join([url, string]))
    print("{}{}".format(url, string))
    print("%s%s" % (url, string))
```